# Is there a way to make the marker’s size to be proportional to the axis in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am plotting positions in a map and I have both my x and y axis in meters and I want to make the marker size in scale with the axis. For example, the x-axis is 500 meters and the y-axis is also 500 m. I want my marker to be 10x50 meters in size, so 1/50 of the x-axis and 1/10 of the y-axis. Is there a way to do this with the ‘MarkerSize’ option?

Comment: you can get the axis lengths using `xr=diff(xlim)` and `yr=diff(ylim)`, then set the `markersize`. But markers are uniform shapes, they take a single size value and cannot be stretched. You might be better off with an `annotation` which lets you draw rectangles within the axes?

Comment: Great idea to use annotation! But I have been trying to use it like this:

Comment: Please [edit] your question if you want to include code or more details

Answer (score 1):

The function to make a variable sized marker in a plot is `scatter`.
Per data point, you can set the following values: X, Y, marker size, and marker color. There is also a `scatter3` version.

Some sample code showing use of the `scatter` function.

```
x = linspace(1,500,50);
y = 500 * rand(size(x));
scatter( x, y, ...      %X, Y positions, same as the plot command
    y, ...              %Use the Y valus as the size input
    ones(size(x)) , ... %All the same color (1 from the axes colormap, like a surface)
    'Filled');          %I like filled markers, rather than outlined. You can omit this.
```

If you want to make a more complex change to each marker (such as creating a rectangle with a varying height and width) then I believe the best way is to use the `patch` function in a loop, once per data point. (This is not that hard, once you get going, although obviously more tedious than a built-in function.)

Comment: OP: `I want my marker to be 10x50 meters in size`, whilst this is nice for individual marker sizing, it only achieves 1D scaling of the marker where the question is asking about scaling by x and y

Comment: Yep, I missed that when I read the question. I've edited the answer, but I don't know of a clean answer to this anymore.